# Laravel 4 Redirect::to doesn't work if called from Password::reset

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a password-reset mechanism which works just fine except for one little strange issue. `Redirect::to('/login')` doesn't work if called during the Password::reset() part.

```
Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password) {
      $user->password = Hash::make($password);
      $user->save();
      return Redirect::to('/login');
});
```

However it works if I put it outside:

```
Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password) {
      $user->password = Hash::make($password);
      $user->save();

});
return Redirect::to('/login');
```

But in this case how do I verify that user's email belongs to the actual token?

Ideally I want to get something like this

```
Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password) {
      $user->password = Hash::make($password);
      $user->save();
      return Redirect::to('/login'); // success you may use your new password
});
return Redirect::to('/reset'); // validation falied try one more time
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [docs on password resets](http://laravel.com/docs/security#password-reminders-and-reset) carefully - You'll note that the `Password::reset()` will return the results of your closure. That's how you can accomplish this with a return of your `Redirect::to` call.

Using the "ideal" version from your question, note the addition of the `return` statement right before `Password::reset()` AND the move of the validation check/redirect to happen BEFORE the call to `Password::reset()`:

```
if( ! VALIDATION FAILED )
{
    return Redirect::to('/reset'); // validation failed, try one more time
}

return Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password) {
      $user->password = Hash::make($password);
      $user->save();
      return Redirect::to('/login'); // success, you may use your new password
});
```

Here's what that looks like in the doc's example:

[image]

Comment: If the password reset fails here, then the closure will not be executed and the Password::reset will redirect back to the same page. Doing that will then run the same password check and redirect back to the same page again, in a loop. Presumably there needs to be some kind of check before the Password::reset in case we are coming from an error, and then redirect back to the form or just display a message in this page?

Comment: Note that on a password reset failure, the above will redirect immediately. There will be no opportunity to flash the input data to the form for re-presenting to the user. To fix this, do a `Input::flash();` before calling `return Password::reset(...)`. You will not want to re-present the password and its confirmation, but it will help to display the user's email again `Form::text('email'), Input::old('email'))`.